# Equivalent of Lagrangians after integration by parts

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, integration, action

Given these three Lagrangians of a spin-1 quantum field $A_\mu$

$$
\begin{align}
\mathscr{L}_1 &= \partial_\mu A^\nu \partial^\mu A_\nu \tag{1}\\
\mathscr{L}_2 &= \partial_\mu A^\mu \partial_\nu A^\nu \tag{2}\\
\mathscr{L}_3 &= \partial_\mu A^\nu \partial_\nu A^\mu \tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

[it is claimed (section 2.1.1)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.4173) that $(1)$ and $(3)$ are equivalent up to a boundary term. I tried integration by parts to verify this. As usual I assumed the boundary terms to vanish (for $V\rightarrow \infty$ anyway), and $$1^\mu = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}^\mu$$

$$
\begin{align}
\int d^4x \mathscr{L}_1 & =
\int d^4x (\partial_\mu A^\nu) (\partial^\mu A_\nu) \\
&= 1_\mu A^\nu \partial^\mu A_\nu \Bigm|_{V} - \int d^4x A^\nu \partial_\mu (\partial^\mu A_\nu)\\
&= -\int d^4x A^\nu \partial_\mu \partial^\mu A_\nu
\end{align}$$

$$
\begin{align}
\int d^4x \mathscr{L}_2 & =
\int d^4x (\partial_\mu A^\mu) (\partial_\nu A^\nu) \\&= 1_\mu A^\mu \partial_\nu A^\nu \Bigm|_{V} - \int d^4x A^\mu \partial_\mu (\partial_\nu A^\nu)\\
&= -\int d^4x A^\mu \partial_\mu \partial_\nu A^\nu
\end{align}$$

$$
\begin{align}
\int d^4x \mathscr{L}_3 & =
\int d^4x (\partial_\mu A^\nu) (\partial_\nu A^\mu) \\&= 1_\mu A^\nu \partial_\nu A^\mu \Bigm|_{V} - \int d^4x A^\nu \partial_\mu (\partial_\nu A^\mu)\\
&= -\int d^4x A^\nu \partial_\nu \partial_\mu A^\mu
\end{align}$$

To me it seems that $\mathscr{L}_2$ and $\mathscr{L}_3$ are equivalent. Is there an error in my calculation or is the statement wrong?

Comment: Only the Feyman lagrangian, ${\cal L}_1$, leads to the correct equation of motion. The other two forms cannot serve as lagrangian.

Comment: @mycts How does this help with answering the question? The document is precisely about finding the correct EOM and eliminating unwanted DoFs, but - at least to me - that is not something that can a priori be seen, hence I want to understand the derivation.

Comment: You seem to be correct indeed. The conclusion (setting a_3 to zero) does not bear impact on what follows though.

Comment: @picop okay, that's reassuring. Of course for the reasoning it doesn't matter if $a1=a3$ or $a2=a3$ since in both cases it follows that we can set $a3=0$ but since I really like to get to the bottom of things I wanted to be sure that my calculation is correct and I'm not missing something.